# How to use random variable to choose correct button in swift

Tags: swift, variables, button, random, iboutlet

The title might not be the best explanation of what I want but I couldn't think of a better way to describe it.

```
@IBOutlet var button0: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var button1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var button2: UIButton!

var num = (arc4random()%3);
```

basically I want to use the variable 'num' to choose which button and make it hidden based off the random number. Is there a way to use the variable in a a simple line like "button(num).hidden = true" or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

you can basically store your buttons into a array of UIButton, and then use this array randomly.

**Code**

```
    self.buttons.append(button0)
self.buttons.append(button1)
        self.buttons.append(button2)
        self.buttons[Int(num)].hidden = true
```

Comment: How do I add all the buttons to an array? I have a bunch made and connected with a storyboard already

Comment: If the buttons is : `var buttons:Array<UIButton> = Array<UIButton>()`, this is working properly for me @EpicDefeater ..

Comment: this isn't working for adding the buttons to an array. They are already connected to the storyboard as IBOutlets and this isn't letting me add them to an array

        'IBOutlet var button1: UIButton!'
        'IBOutlet var button2: UIButton!'
        'IBOutlet var button3: UIButton!'
    
        'var buttonList:Array<UIButton> = Array<UIButton>()'
  
        'self.buttonList.append(button1)'

Comment: The code : 
` @IBOutlet weak var button0: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
    var num = (arc4random()%3);
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        var ar:Array<UIButton> = Array<UIButton>()
        ar.append(self.button0)
        ar.append(self.button1)
        ar.append(self.button2)
        ar[Int(num)].hidden = true`

Comment: please accept my answer, my code's working from my github, just test it

Answer (score 0):

```
[button0, button1, button2][num]
```

Comment: can you explain this a little more? what is this exactly doing? creating an array for the buttons?

Comment: a temporary array is created of the tree buttons; then your random number is used as an index in the array, effectively selecting a random button. The result of the statement is a button at the `num` index, so you can go ahead and change it's properties: `var randomButton = [button0, button1, button2][num]`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, all you want to do is create an array of UIButtons!, and then set array[num].enable = false.

Comment: Ok but how do I add all of the buttons that Ive made to an array then?

Comment: You could probably do something like this: var list = [button0...]

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = Int(arc4random_uniform(3))
let buttons:[UIButton] = [button0,button1,button2]

buttons[num].hidden = !buttons[num].hidden
```

Comment: When I try to make the Array with these elements in it it gives me an error saying "'ViewController.Type' does not have a member named 'button0'"

Comment: put it inside viewDidLoad or a custom method or IBAction

Answer (score 0):

Create an array that stores all your UIButtons

```
var buttonsArray: [UIButton]!
```

Access one of the UIButtons from the Array randomly and hide the accessed UIButton

```
var randomNum: Int = Int(arc4random()%3)
var button = buttonsArray[randomNum]
button.hidden = true
```